# Creating URL string for call to OrganizationData.svc using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011

Currently, I have two different methods to decide which version of CRM that my JS runs on. The addresses are similar but differ still, depending on whether it's on-line or on-premise. I've tried to integrate them but it's still depending on a variable as the code below shows. What would be a neater solution (one that will pick the right URL to the service for organization data)?

```javascript
var isOnLine = true;
var organizationName = Xrm.Page.context.getOrgUniqueName();
var organizationUrl 
  = "http" + (isOnLine ? "s" : "") + "://" 
  + parent.window.location.host 
  + (isOnLine ? "" : "/" + organizationName)
  + "/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc";
```

Most of all, I'd like a method of obtaining the service's URL by a call to *something* (not sure what, though). If it's not possible, I'd like to be suggested a method of detecting if the currently run script is deployed in on-line or on-premise installation.

It's also of some importance that the method (if any available) will work independently of the version (or at the very least that it checks using *if* statement what version that is the currently run).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I wouldn't use *parent.window.location.host* (not even sure if it's supported).
2. You get *organizationName* disregarding whether it's on-line version or on-premise (needlessly).
3. The call will fail if an on-premise is set up on secured HTTP (or you'll need yet an other flag).
4. My suggestion would be to focus on CRM 2011 (the older version 4 uses SOAP, not REST).
5. For the actual *OrganizationData* service you can use the function below (or just embed the line).

```
function getOrganizationDataService(){
  return Xrm.Page.context.getServerUrl() 
    + "/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc";
}
```

Comment: @CRMconfusee Not sure. As far I'm informed, there will be support for REST services, so the most dramatic change in the name I'd expect is that the year *2011* might be exchange for *2013*. However, please keep in mind that those are but speculations on my part.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest having a look at this sample: [Sample: Create, Retrieve, Update and Delete Using the REST Endpoint with JavaScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334427.aspx).

In particular:

> **sample_/Scripts/SDK.REST.js**   A reusable, generic library that simplifies asynchronous data operations using the REST Endpoint for
>   Web resources.

In particular the first few functions which effectively build REST OrganizationData endpoint like so (I've cut out a couple of steps here, so make sure to look at the sample code):

```
Xrm.Page.context.getServerUrl() + "/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/";
```

Comment: The code you showed the link to seems to guard for a slash at the end of *getServerUrl* call. Do I need to worry about it? (I asked a new question on the subject and refered you in it.)

Comment: I dont know for sure, its an Microsoft sample though - so yes its probably worth guarding about the slash.